# Filter certain values and multiple previous rows with another condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, lag

I have time series cross sectional dataset. In `value` column, the value becomes TRUE after some FALSE values. I want to filter the dataset to keep all TRUE values with previous 4 FALSE values.

The example dataset and desired dataset are following:

```
df = tibble(country = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                        "B","B","B","B","B","B","B", 
                        "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                        "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"),
            year = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015", "2016",
                     "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015", "2016",
                     "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015", "2016",
                     "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015", "2016"),
            value = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
                      TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
                      TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
                      TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

outcome = tibble(country = c("A","A","A","A","A",
                             "B","B","B","B","B", 
                             "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                             "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"),
                 year = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015",
                          "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015",
                          "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015",
                          "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014","2015"),
                 value = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
                           FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
                           FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
                           FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "reverse" cumulative sum:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country,cum=rev(cumsum(rev(value)))) %>%
  filter(n()==5) %>%
  ungroup%>%
  select(-cum)

# A tibble: 20 x 3
   country year  value
   <chr>   <chr> <lgl>
 1 A       2011  FALSE
 2 A       2012  FALSE
 3 A       2013  FALSE
 4 A       2014  FALSE
 5 A       2015  TRUE 
 6 B       2011  FALSE
 7 B       2012  FALSE
 8 B       2013  FALSE
 9 B       2014  FALSE
10 B       2015  TRUE 
11 C       2011  FALSE
12 C       2012  FALSE
13 C       2013  FALSE
14 C       2014  FALSE
15 C       2015  TRUE 
16 D       2011  FALSE
17 D       2012  FALSE
18 D       2013  FALSE
19 D       2014  FALSE
20 D       2015  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `lag`, here's another approach using `cumsum` and `lag`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country, 
           tmp = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0))) %>% 
  filter(n() == 5) %>% 
  ungroup %>% select(-tmp)

 #> # A tibble: 20 x 3
 #>    country year  value
 #>    <chr>   <chr> <lgl>
 #>  1 A       2011  FALSE
 #>  2 A       2012  FALSE
 #>  3 A       2013  FALSE
 #>  4 A       2014  FALSE
 #>  5 A       2015  TRUE 
 #>  6 B       2011  FALSE
 #>  7 B       2012  FALSE
 #>  8 B       2013  FALSE
 #>  9 B       2014  FALSE
 #> 10 B       2015  TRUE 
 #> 11 C       2011  FALSE
 #> 12 C       2012  FALSE
 #> 13 C       2013  FALSE
 #> 14 C       2014  FALSE
 #> 15 C       2015  TRUE 
 #> 16 D       2011  FALSE
 #> 17 D       2012  FALSE
 #> 18 D       2013  FALSE
 #> 19 D       2014  FALSE
 #> 20 D       2015  TRUE
```

Comment: Firstly, I want to thank you for your help. However, it did not solve my problem because of my bad explanation. My dataset is more complex than my examples. Basically, what I want to do is to find the repetitive patterns in one column. The repetitive pattern is 4 FALSE observations and one or many TRUE observations followed by 4 FALSE observations. Do you have any idea that solves this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested to me. You can access the question via the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086554/finding-repetitive-pattern-in-one-column-in-r Many thanks for your help and effort in advance.